# Constant vector differentiation

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Just wondering whether the derivative of a constant vector is $0$ or $\vec{0}$.
Perhaps $\vec{0}$ since there is no "vector" change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed by definition

$$\vec v(t)' = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\vec v(t+h)-\vec v(t)}{h}$$

and for $\vec v(t)=\vec {v}_0$ it is equal to $\vec 0$.

Comment: alright, bless you!